# Prestashop Custom Hook

Tags: prestashop

I am new at `Prestashop`. I want to create a new themes, it has fixed-top `navigation`(Sticky), with Permanent Link(Contact-Sitemap) and Currencies-Languages inside of it.

My question is How we arrange the content of `{HOOK_TOP}` ?
I know that it's generated from Module

**"Permanent Link"** can be hard-coded, because it's static, but what about the Currencies-Languages?

Do we need to create a custom hook and module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a few ways for this depending on your requirements.

But best way is to create a simple module and hook it at top at HOOK_TOP . Then using positions for the module at admin, adjust its place. Some times, this will not work, because of the HTML problems and you will not get what results do you need, so you will need to adjust the css and html for this.

Easy way is to just place that contents directly in the header.tpl file, if the contents are static. This way is more efficient and easy. But still it may cause a little bit problem, because what you will do if, the contents you are placing comes in the middle of two modules like currency block or languages block. So this will be more good, if you place that static contents with in a module tpl file which best suits the place for it.

There is no need to create a new hook for it.

I hope it will help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-coded in hearder.tpl (or where the {HOOK_TOP} is placed ) to show your static content. But it is better to create an new module for your static content and hook into hook_top.